# Joomla SEO doesn't work after migration

Tags: joomla, seo, migration

I have a Joomla 1.5 website and I enabled SEO on it. I moved it to different location with different DNS and now SEO doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Three checkboxes ("Search Engine Friendly URLs", "Use Apache mod_rewrite" and "Add suffix to URLs") on global configuration page regarding SEO are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the new server definitely an apache web server?
Is mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

If the answer to either of the above is no, then you have problems. For the first you'll need to change servers. For the second you'll need to get the server administrators to enable (and possibly install) mod_rewrite.

Is your website in a sub-folder? For example /joomla/ for example.
If so you need to edit the RewriteBase line within the .htaccess file.
Change the line from
RewriteBase /
to 
RewriteBase /joomla/

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `htaccess` to `.htaccess`.

Comment: It's already done by moving files from the original location.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more problems, but I think you should start checking this:

1) You have the right .htaccess file in your joomla root and it is readable by your Apache user.

2) Go to the administrator > Site > Global Configuration and check you have "Search Engine Friendly URL's" and "Use Apache mod_rewrite" to "Yes".

3) Make sure that the Apache you are using has all the modules needed.